# Does anyone have any suggestions for some cello pieces to improve my comfort with treble clef/higher positions?

Tags: technique, cello

I've just finished playing "Allegro Appassionato" by Saint-Saëns and the first movement of Cello Concerto No. 1 in E Minor by Brahms. My teacher suggested I start playing Eduoard Lalo's Cello Concerto in D Minor as a next piece. However, I don't feel very comfortable playing in treble clef, as well as just higher positions in general. If anyone has any suggestions for "in between" pieces or etudes to work on that I would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome! I'll ask the obvious question: have you asked your teacher? Also, I'm afraid recommendations are one of the [topics not covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But you certainly should be able to *get* such recommendations from any good cello teacher (or even advanced cellist)!

Comment: Requests for specific pieces usually get closed quickly - it's not part of the site's regime, I'm sorry. As far as playing on the dusty part of the fingerboard, why not transpose some pieces an octave higher, or, if you're feeling brave, into oter keys that use the higher parts? Or even from alto to treble clef, writing out the new dots?

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I didn't realize this question was against the site's policy. I will be sure to do what is suggested.